# Is there a tool to do ast 2 python source code for Python 2.x?

Tags: python

I've seen codegen http://dev.pocoo.org/hg/sandbox/file/868ea20c2c1d/ast/ but doent works with all the files and ast2src which only works with Python 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Ive patched [codegen](http://dev.pocoo.org/hg/sandbox/file/868ea20c2c1d/ast/) con make it work with my sources: http://svn.juanjoconti.com.ar/dyntaint/trunk/wrapstrings/gen/

Answer (score 0):

[You could convert the 3.1 source to 2x using 3to2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/3to2).

It's a utility for back-porting python3 scripts back to python2.

*Note: 3to2 isn't the standard user-submitted PYPI project. It has been vetted by the core dev team and was the one of the [Google Summer of Code](http://socghop.appspot.com/gsoc/student_project/show/google/gsoc2009/python/t124024625558) projects last year*